# PHP loop through array with name

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach, echo

How can I loop through an array like this and retrieve the id and echo it to the screen? Also how can I do a loop and find the one with the highest id?

```
Array
(
    [articles] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 650
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 649
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 645
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 399
)
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `foreach`

```
foreach ($array['articles'] as $value)
{
   echo "Id is: ".$value['id'];
}
```

And you can get with [max()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php) function:

```
foreach($array['articles'] as $article)
{
    $ids[] = $article['id'];
}
echo "Max Id is: ".max($ids);
```

Or you can do get value and max id with one `foreach`.

```
foreach($array['articles'] as $article)
{
    echo "Id is: ".$article['id'];
    $ids[] = $article['id'];
}

echo "Max Id is: ".max($ids);
```

Comment: Its echo is this: Id is: ArrayId is: ArrayId is: ArrayId is: ArrayId is: ArrayId is: ArrayId is: ArrayId is: ArrayId is: ArrayId is: ArrayId is: ArrayId is: ArrayId is: Array

Comment: Sorry, i missed. Updated!

Comment: Your max function will throw the error @Bora for that array
<b>Notice</b>:  Array to string conversion

Comment: Aow! You right. Your array is multidimensional. You can get with `foreach` again. Updated!

Answer (score 0):

Say `$arr['articles']` contains your array.Then using a [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) you can loop through the array and just echo it.

```
$arr = array('articles' => array(
                                 '0' => array('id' => 650),
                                 '1' => array('id' => 649),
                                 '2' => array('id' => 645),
                                 '3' => array('id' => 399)
                                )
           );
foreach($arr['articles'] as $val){
  echo $val['id'].'</br>';
}
```

Comment: It just echos: ArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArray

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
foreach ($arrayvar['articles'] as $value)
{
   echo $value['id']."<br>";
}
```